# hex representation of german umlaut to string

Tags: ruby, string, encoding, diacritics

I have a String that has non ascii characters encoded as "\\'fc" (without quotes), where fc is hex 252 which corresponds to the german ü umlaut.

I managed to find all occurences and can replace them. But I have not been able to convert the fc to an ü.

```
"fc".hex.chr
```

gives me another representation...but if I do

```
puts "fc".hex.chr
```

I get nothing back...

Thanks in advance

PS: I'm working on ruby 1.9 and have

```
# coding: utf-8
```

at the top of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
puts "fc".hex.chr(Encoding::UTF_8)
```

Ruby docs:

- [int.chr](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Integer.html#M000191)
- [Encoding](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Encoding.html)

UPDATE:

Jason True is right.  `fc` is invalid UTF-8.  I have no idea why my example works!

Comment: Probably because 0xfc.chr.encoding returns ascii-8bit. chr(Encoding::UTF_8) converts the source encoding into the destination encoding.

Comment: @JasonTrue: Does that depend on the value of `Encoding.default_internal`?

Comment: Just upgraded to Ruby 1.9.1 (Ruby 1.9.0 doesn't have that method), and apparently not.  It's still `ASCII-8BIT`.

Comment: I was using Ruby 1.9.2 but I did that from irb. There's also the possibility that the behavior is different depending on other environment factors.

Answer (score 2):

fc is not the correct UTF-8 codepoint for that character; that's iso-8859-1 or windows-1252. The UTF-8 encoding for ü is the two-byte sequence, c3bc. Further, FC is not a valid UTF-8 sequence.

Since UTF-8 is assumed in Ruby 1.9, you should be able to get the literal u-umlaut with: `"\xc3\xbc"`

Comment: the question was to get the corresponding utf-8 while only having the iso-8859 representation. I knew how to get an u-umlaut but not how to get it from the iso representation...but still thanks

Comment: Sorry, that aspect of the question wasn't specified explicitly, so I presumed you just had a misunderstanding about how UTF-8 works.

Comment: Though you didn't answer my question you are right: I don't really know how UTF-8 works...And I still hate every encoding problem that occurs...these are the hardest one to tackle for me. Have a look at the complete snippet I used to convert my strange text...a hell: http://pastie.org/1737333

Comment: Is this a file or database record that you're trying to convert? If so, there are probably better ways of doing that than trying to hack it with regular expressions. For example, consider `File.open('text.htm','r:iso-8859-1:utf-8').readlines.to_s`

Comment: Alternatively, if you know Ruby has misinterpreted the encoding of the source content, you can usually do something like: mystring.force_encoding('iso-8859-1').encode('utf-8')

Comment: Yes, the encoding is no fun after 1.8.x - ruby was more fun during the 1.8.x era. I can feel with you.